# Query a set of nodes where a text node is contained in a collection

Tags: xml, xpath

I work in insurance and we have our policies encoded as XML. I am trying to get all StateCd nodes that match a certain set of states from a policy's XML. Currently I have this as my query:

```
/CoPolicy/CoLobs/CoLob/WkPolicy/WkStates/WkState[WkStateCd != 'FL' and WkStateCd != 'IL']/WkStateCd
```

This will get me all the nodes that are state Illinois and Florida. However I want to add several states to this list. If I just create a never ending list of "WkStateCd != 'XX' and WkStateCd != 'YY' and..." that's a pain to read and also seems like bad practice. I want to do something like:

```
Dim states As String[] = ["AL", "FL", "DC", ... ]
Dim xPath As String =  "/CoPolicy/CoLobs/CoLob/WkPolicy/WkStates/WkState[WkStateCd In states]/WkStateCd"
```

Is there an easy/clean way to do this in XPath?

Answer (score 0):

In XPath, the equality operator acts like an "in" when the right side is a sequence.  It will evaluate to true if the left side equals any item in the sequence.  If your processor supports XPath 2.0+ you can structure your XPath expression as:

```
/CoPolicy/CoLobs/CoLob/WkPolicy/WkStates/WkState[WkStateCd = ('AL',FL','DC',...)]/WkStateCd
```

Prior to XPath 2.0, it is not possible to use the comma operator to form a sequence like this directly in the XPath expression.

If you want to exclude states in the list (e.g. do a "not in") you would typically put a not() around the condition:

```
not(WkStateCd = ('AL',FL','DC',...))
```

A classic mistake that many make with the "not in" scenario is to try:

```
WkStateCd != ('AL',FL','DC',...)
```

which means something different than a traditional "not in" when sequences are involved.

Comment: Note that this syntax is XPath 2.0. There's no equivalent in XPath 1.0. The OP didn't specify an XPath version which often indicates that they're still on 1.0.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I added a brief qualification to the answer.

Comment: @DavidDenenberg, the `=` can be used the same way in XPath 1.0, only there is no way to construct a sequence in XPath 1.0 with a comma operator, all you could do is pass in a variable with a node-set and do e.g. `[WkStateCd = $States]`. So your explanation with 'In XPath (version 2.0+), the equality operator acts like an "in" ' is a bit misleading, the "in" like or "any item on the left equals at least one item on the right" is the same in XPath 1.0; you simply have no way in XPath 1.0 to construct a sequence or node-set of strings, like you can do in XPath 2 with the comma operator.

Comment: Thank you for the further clarification.  I reworked the answer accordingly (I hope).